# Reinstalling Broken PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, postgresql

After upgrading Ubuntu from Precise to Trusty, I was attempting to upgrade PostgreSQL from 9.1 to 9.3 and have hit a bit of a snag. When I ran `pg_upgrade` in "check" mode, it complained about being unable to load the library `pljava` even after I had dropped the language.

After much head-scratching, I had the brilliant idea to try a clean reinstall of PostgreSQL 9.1 and so blithely uninstalled the package, only to discover that I cannot now install it again, as Synaptic reports the package as being broken. Thus, I now have the 9.3 binaries and a set of data files created with 9.1 and no idea how to safely access them.

Could someone please tell me **EITHER**

1. how to reinstall PostgreSQL 9.1 so I may complete the migration process, or
2. how to complete the migration process safely without reinstalling the old binaries?

Comment: Run [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgupgrade.html) command line tool.

Comment: That requires the 9.1 binaries, which I no longer have installed.

Comment: My bad. I was under the impression that you only need the old version data files to run against pg_upgrade. If you have a windows manager installed you may want to install 9.1 using the enterprisedb installer. It will install under /opt so its not system dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem appears to be that I was trying to use Synaptic Package Manager to do the install. Running the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge postgresql-9.1
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
sudo pg_createcluster -d /path/to/existing/data 9.1 main
```

cleared up the installation problem.